# How to tie a folder of multiple images to data? GraphQL GatsbyJS

Tags: html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, graphql, gatsby

I want to tie a folder with multiple images to my data.

I have some data:

```
[
   {
      "title": "data1",
      "images" : "./relimages/first-data/",
      "cardimages" : "./relimages/main-page-card-images/1.jpg",
   },
   {
      "title": "data2",
      "images" : "./relimages/second-data/",
      "cardimages" : "./relimages/main-page-card-images/2.jpg",
   },
   {
      "title": "data3",
      "images" : "./relimages/third-data/",
      "cardimages" : "./relimages/main-page-card-images/3.jpg",
   }
]
```

But when I query them with graphql, I only have a string : "./relimages/first-data"

Although, my cardimages data entry is seen as an image directly.

How can I make my query see that as a folder, instead of just returning the string.

I want this code to work:

```html
<h1>{data.title}</h1>
data.images.edges.map(image => return (<img src={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid.src}/>))
```

Here's my current GraphQL query:

```
 query flagquery {
  allDataRoJson {
    edges {
      node {
        images {
          edges {
            node {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid {
                  src
                }
              }
            }
          }
          cardimages {
            id
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                originalImg
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But my image data entry is seen as a string, instead of a folder. Is this possible somehow?

Error is:

> Field \"images\" must not have a selection since type \"String\" has no subfields

Comment: I didn't understand what you trying to do, but doing `data.images.edges.foreach` surely a bug, you can't return anything from `forEach`

Comment: I meant ```map```. I just want my data to point to a folder of images that are accessible with gatsby-image

Comment: @DennisVash i want my data at the beggining of the post to contain:

Comment: A title, an array of images, and an image. That array of images is formed from the folder images: